# Receiving memory-related runtime error & searching for tips on code efficiency

Tags: c++, xcode, performance

I compiled my code numerous times and receive a memory-related runtime error. I am new to programming and couldn't figure out the issue. If someone can assist me in understanding why this is occurring and give me a few tips on how to clean up my code/make it more efficient I would greatly appreciate it!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
void chefsMenuitems();

void chefsMenuitems(int P[], int arr_size) {
     int count = 0;
     int current_item = 0;
     int n = 0;
     int i = 0;
     for (int j = 0; j < arr_size; j++ ) {
        while(P[j] > 0) {
           for ( i = 0; current_item < P[j]; i++) {
                current_item = pow(2,(i));
                if (current_item > P[j]){
                  current_item = pow(2,(i - 1));
                  break;
                }
           }  

           P[j] = P[j] - current_item;   
           current_item = 0;
           n++;
       }
       count++;
       std::cout << "The number of menu items for price " << count << " are: " << n << "\n";
       n = 0;
       current_item = 0;
    }
 }

int main() {
    int T = 0;
    int P[] = {0};
    int arr_size;

    std::cout << "Please enter the number of test cases: \n";
    std::cin >> T;

    while(T < 1 || T > 5 ) {
       std::cout << "Test cases must be between 1 & 5 inclusive: \n";
       std::cin >> T;        
    }

    arr_size = T;   
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        std::cout << "Please enter the amount you are willing to spend: \n";
        std::cin >> P[i];

        while(P[i] < 1 || P[i] > pow(10, 5)) {
          std::cout << "The amount you are willing to spend must be between 1 and 10^5 inclusive: \n";
          std::cin >> P[i];     
        }
    }

    chefsMenuitems(P, arr_size);         
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

> ```
> int P[] = { 0 };
> ```

is an array of one element but you try to access up to 5 elements.

Use a `std::vector<int>` if you want an array-like container with a size not known at compile-time or waste some space by defining an array of the largest possible size for expected input:

```
int P[5] = {};
```

Comment: Ok sorry, first time.